# Azure Function time running increase after each run

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-synapse

I have HTTP Azure function which is triggered from Synapse. I have loop pipeline where I call function 4 times with only one different parameter in each iteration. I am doing this to avoid timeout of 240s.
If I run only once, with any of 4 parameters it last about 1.5 min. Different parameter does not have impact on execution time.

What I have noticed is that when run function like this, execution time increase. For example first time it is 1.5 min, next around 2 min and when it come to last run it is more then 4 min what led to fail.

I have tried to put wait activity after function run (wait 300s), but it does not help.

Function is on Premium v2 P1V2.

Does anyone know why is this happening? Is this something I should change in Azure Function settings?